# How to Remove a Part of String from an HTML Element using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html element:

```
<p> Top Ten Miler </p>
```

I would like to remove string "Top Ten" from:

```
<p> Top Ten Miler </p>
```

So out should be straight:

```
<p> Miler </p>
```

How can I do it using JavaScript or jQuery on windows load?

Comment: with your string `'Top Ten Miler'.replace('Top Ten ','')`

Comment: No Miler is from variable. I have 1000 entries. Like 

Top Ten Miler 
Top Ten Thriller 
Top Ten Dealer 

I want to remove "Top Ten" only at a time from all.

Comment: you can use js regex `var x = 'Top Tem Miler Top Ten AAA'; x.replace(/Top Ten /g, '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `p` text and replace.

```js
$('p').text($('p').text().replace('Top Ten',''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Top Ten Miler </p>
```

Or if your `<p>`is inside any div and div have any `class or id` you can use that `class or id`.In below snippet I use `class`:

```js
$('.yourclass > p').text($('.yourclass > p').text().replace('Top Ten',''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='yourclass'><p> Top Ten Miler </p></div>
```

Comment: Cool,  Thanks a lot.

But I don't know why people are down grading my question! Strange!

Comment: If answer helps you validate answer for future. Happy coding :).

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace` method

```js
var x = 'Top Ten Miler';
var newString = x.replace('Top Ten', '');
console.log(newString.trim()) //trim to replace any white space
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say you want to remove `xxx` by `yyy` on every node of `span` or `p` or `div`.  This is generic code you can try.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('span[data-replace][data-replace-by]')
        .each(function(i, el) {
            var html = $(el).html();  
            var oldValue = $(el).data('replace');
            var newValue = $(el).data('replace-by');
            html = html.replace(oldValue, newValue);
            $(el).html(html);        
        });
        
    });
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span data-replace='deepak' data-replace-by='sharma'>
this is deepak sharma
</span>
<br/>
<span data-replace='this is' data-replace-by=''>
this is deepak sharma
</span>
<br/>
<span data-replace='sharma' data-replace-by='SHARMA'>
this is deepak sharma
</span>
<br/>
<span data-replace='This'>
This will not change, as no replace-by specified.
</span>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each instance and replace the text you want

```js
$('#top-tens p').each(function(index, element){
  let text = $(element).text().replace('Top Ten ', '');
  $(element).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-tens">
<p>Top Ten Miler</p>
<p>Top Ten Thriller</p>
<p>Top Ten Dealer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = "Top Ten Miler";
var res = str.substring(7, 13);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.split()`, like this:

```
let cutVal = "Top Ten Miler";    // Or Top Ten whatever
let arryVal = cutVal.split(" "); // Split string into three parts
console.log(arryVal[2]);         // Grab the third part

// output is
Miler
```